# Error when trying to format an Excel column with vbScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using vbScript to run a procedure on an MS Excel file.  The goal of this procedure is 4 fold.

1. Remove all "-"'s from Column C in the file
2. Format Column C as "000000000" (this column contains social security numbers, when I remove the dashes I want to preserve the leading zeroes)
3. Format Column E as "yyyymmdd"
4. Save the file

The below code is what I am using.  I am able to achieve Goal #1 and Goal #3 perfectly.  I am unable to achieve the 2nd goal, basically once I remove the "-"'s the values do not reflect the leading zeroes.  When it comes to goal #4, the Save As dialogue box pops up and I am forced to manually save.  I do not want this, rather I want the file to just save in the same location with the same file name.

```
Const FromValue = "-"
Const ToValue = ""

Dim objExcel : Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
Set objWorkbook =  objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\charlie-tufts\Desktop\Practice Reports\VCA Termination Report Result.csv")
Dim objWorksheet : Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim objRangeSSN : Set objRangeSSN = objWorksheet.range("C:C")
Dim objRangeDate : Set objRangeDate = objWorksheet.range("E:E")




objRangeSSN.Replace FromValue, ToValue
objRangeSSN.numberformat = "000000000"
objRangeDate.numberformat = "yyyymmdd"

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
objExcel.Save
objExcel.Quit
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

-Charlie

Comment: Can you try with `objExcel.Save True` ?

Comment: I ended up with the same result

Comment: Just try `Worksheets(1).Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "000000000"` and see if it formats correctly. If so, it's an issue with the variable.

Comment: You're working on a .csv file. If you want to use number formats I suspect you need to save it in an .xls* format.

Comment: @xidgel When I used number format with objRangeDate it worked fine so I would suspect that this is not the issue